# How do I get a group of text and listboxes to properly vertically align with even spacing between?

Tags: html, listbox, drop-down-menu

I am constructing a webpage using fairly elementary techniques.  I have three rows on a certain part of the webpage, each of which is structured as .  The text units and the listbox units of the different rows are in perfect horizontal alignment, but the vertical spacing between the listboxes is inconsistent.  Furthermore the vertical alignment of each listbox in relation to its paired text is different.  I've tried readjusting the table structure and experimenting with valign, but to no avail.  How do I fix this so that it looks neat?  Thanks!

Comment: Some example code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the height of each td by css like

```
td {
    height: 50px
}
```

also you should check out some tutorials on how to design forms without using tables http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/examples/exampleitem/tableless_forms/

Comment: I tried putting it in like <td style="height:50px;">, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <form>
     <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
           <td>
              <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0">
                 <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="50%">
                       Please choose the test category:
                    </td>
                        <td align="left" width="50%">
                           <form action="">
                              <select name="categories" style="width:20%;"></select>
                           </form>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <br />
         <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0">
                     <tr>
                        <td align="right" width="50%" valign="center">
                           Please choose the test:
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" width="50%" valign="center">
                           <form action="">
                              <select name="tests" style="width:20%;"></select>
                           </form>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <br />
         <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0">
                     <tr>
                        <td align="right" width="50%">
                           Please choose the difficulty:
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" width="50%">
                           <form action="">
                              <select name="difficulties" style="width:20%;"></select>
                           </form>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </form>
```

This is only the present state.  I've tried other things with it.

---

Edit:
That includes the non-existence of any valign things in there.  When I tried adding them, nothing happened.